# Nginx-Ingress-Controller limit number of rps to deployment

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, rate-limiting

I am having issues serving data under high load and would like to return a 503 if the total rps to a specific deployment exceeds a certain number. I was playing around with their rate limiting but that limits per client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler approach, I would try, would be to limit the resources (CPU and Memory) for that deployment. You can also separate the ingress controller for that service and limit resources for that as well.

Alternatively service meshes provide more customizations, for example `istio` provides [ConnectionPoolSettings](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ConnectionPoolSettings) for `DestinationRule` objects that can serve similar purpose.

Additionally, there is also an experimental feature of [traffic shaping](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#support-traffic-shaping) that might be helpful but that requires updating your CNI configuration.

---

For reference: @Dylan figured out that [limit_req_zone](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_zone) Nginx configuration can be used with `$host` to achieve this as well. In order to do this, (1) update your nginx ingress controller config map and add the `http-snippet`

```yaml
data:
  http-snippet: |
    limit_req_zone $host zone=queue:10m rate=1r/s;
```

You may have to restart your controller pods to pick up the new configuration. (2) Apply the configuration to the Ingress using `configuration-snippet`:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      limit_req zone=queue burst=12 delay=8;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I would be able to do exactly what I need if the 'http-snippets' section of the configmap actually had an effect on the nginx.conf. Creating a req-zone based on the host this will effectively do what I need, however, the configmap does not change the config one bit :)

Comment: Hi Dylan. Saw your GitHub bug issue. You have a typo in your config map. It's `http-snippet`, not plural. I just tested on my local cluster and it's being picked up by the stable/nginx-ingress community chart. I had to restart my `ingress-controller` pod for it to load the new configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ultimately figured that out, however, I am still having issues setting the global server snippet. I found a workaround by adding a configuration-snippet annotation on all of the ingress's, though.

Comment: I have updated the answer with your findings for future ref. Let me know if I missed anything. Thanks